# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, insert

I have a table with string values in the format of **Friday 20th April 2012** in a field called `Film_Release`

I am looping through and I want to convert them in `datetime` and roll them out into another table. My second table has a column called `Films_Date`, with a format of `DATE`. I am receiving this error

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

```
$dateFromDB = $info['Film_Release'];
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y",$dateFromDB); //( http:php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
```

Then I insert `$newdate` into the table through an insert command.

Why am I be getting such an error?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Because `$newDate` is an object of type `DateTime`, not a string. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) is explicit:

> Returns new `DateTime` object formatted according to the specified
>   format.

If you want to convert from a string to `DateTime` back to string to change the format, call [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) at the end to get a formatted string out of your `DateTime`.

```
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $dateFromDB);
$newDate = $newDate->format('d/m/Y'); // for example
```

Comment: Hi, ive tried and i get this error - Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: @DIM3NSION: Not possible with the code above unless `createFromFormat` does not return an object, which means it returned `false` because the input was invalid. Read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and fix the input.

Comment: What type of field would i use to insert $new date? i have it working now

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
$Date = $row['valdate']->format('d/m/Y'); // the result will 01/12/2015
```

NOTE: `$row['valdate']` its a value date in the database

Answer (score 5):

Use this:  `$newDate = $dateInDB->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Twig templates for Symfony, you can use the classic `{{object.date_attribute.format('d/m/Y')}}` to obtain the desired formatted date.

Comment: This work's for me, but i only use this.  .format('d/m/Y') 
myObject  .format('d/m/Y')

Answer (score 1):

```
$Date = $row['Received_date']->format('d/m/Y');
```

then it cast date object from given in database

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert `$newdate` into your db. You need to convert it to a string first. Use the `DateTime::format` method to convert back to a string.

Comment: hi, i have tried to use format but receive an error - Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure there is a film release date; if the date is missing you will not be able to format on a non-object.

```
if ($info['Film_Release']){ //check if the date exists
   $dateFromDB = $info['Film_Release'];
   $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $dateFromDB);
   $newDate = $newDate->format('d/m/Y'); 
} else {
   $newDate = "none"; 
}
```

or

```
 $newDate = ($info['Film_Release']) ? DateTime::createFromFormat("l dS F Y", $info['Film_Release'])->format('d/m/Y'): "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of offtopic, but i come here from googling the same error. 
For me this error appeared when i was selecting datetime field from mssql database and than using it later in php-script.
like this:

```
$SQL="SELECT Created
FROM test_table";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $SQL);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$Row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);


$SQL="INSERT INTO another_test_table (datetime_field) VALUES ('".$Row['Created']."')";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($con, $SQL);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

the INSERT statement was giving error: `Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`

I realized that you **CAN'T** just select the datetime from database:

```
SELECT Created FROM test_table
```

**BUT** you have to use CONVERT for this field:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(24),Created) as Created FROM test_table
```

Comment: use the params Kenny, They're there for it and will then magically be converted from \DateTime objects ``sqlsrv_query($con, "INSERT INTO tablename (dtfield) VALUES(?)", array($datetime))``

Answer (score 0):

For those coming from Javascript like me: **you can't simply echo the DateTime object and expect a nicely formatted default string as the output!**

You have to use the **`format()`** function and input a custom format like `$dateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d')` to get a string representation of the date stored in the object. ([Syntax reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters))

[There are some default constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetimeinterface.constants.types) you can use though, and this one is the closest to Javascript's default format:

```php
echo (new DateTime())->format( DateTime::RSS );
// Fri, 29 Dec 2023 00:48:56 +0000
```

Alternatively, use `print_r( $dateTimeObject )` for a quick glance at the datetime value :)

```php
print_r( (new DateTime()) );
/*(
  [date] => 2023-12-29 00:55:38.670878
  [timezone_type] => 3
  [timezone] => UTC
)*/
```