# DateTime input convert between timezones in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have an input box that grabs local time

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
echo "<input type='datetime-local' name='fromDate' class='dates'>";
```

When I enter `12-31-2014 10:00:00 PM` in the input

```
echo $_POST['fromDate'];
```

Response: `2014-12-31T22:00:00`

```
$test = new DateTime($_POST['fromDate']);
echo $test;
```

I get `2014-12-31T22:00:00 America/Los_Angeles`

Then when I convert

```
$from_dateGMT  = new DateTime($_POST['fromDate'], new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
$from_date = $from_dateGMT->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
echo $from_date;
```

I get `2014-12-31T22:12:00 UTC`, which is the same time listed above and should be adding 8 hours.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't deal with dates/times in PHP ever, so this is a learning experience for me.

Comment: The error is probably because you're trying to use a `DateTime` **object** in a **string** context. But the line of code in your question *alone* shouldn't cause that error. Please show more code. (also, take a look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10209941/1438393).)

Comment: You were right, it was a formatting issue. I've fixed that but it isn't converting now. I'll update the info above.

Comment: Updated code and issue above.

Comment: Made some additional edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work

```
$test = new DateTime($_POST['fromDate'], new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$test->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
echo $test->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

At least that is how it is done in php manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php