# get date form DateTime object

Tags: php, date, datetime

How can i take the date from the DateTime Object in a variable? Not even needed to format the date - `Y-m-d` as it is will be enough

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-07-24 10:14:31
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Saw a similar question but the answer didn't have the willing effect so decided to make a new Question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime($object->date))

Comment: so do `$dtObj->date;`

Comment: If your object is a regular [`DateTime` object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) then you shouldn't have to go to all that effort. It should be as simple as `$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');`, assuming your original variable is called `$dt`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), do:

```
echo $your_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: @gxthegreat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array ( 'date' => '2014-07-24 10:14:3', 'timezone_type' => '3',  'timezone] => Europe/Berlin' );

$date = date_create($array['date']);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```