# <b>Catchable fatal error</b>: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to perform an insert query into a sql server. However, every time I perform the query it just returns with

> **Catchable fatal error**:  Object of class DateTime could not be
>   converted to string in **C:\xampp\htdocs\fusion\insertTrade.php**
>   on line **29**

I can't understand what's going on because at that line I'm not even doing anything with datetime. Can anyone help out?

insertTrade.php:

```
$fullName = $_POST["fullName"];
  $ticSymbol = $_POST["tickSymbol"];
  $limitOrder = $_POST["limitOrder"];
  $limitPrice = $_POST["limitPrice"];
  $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
  $contingentOrder = $_POST["contingentOrder"];
  $contingentLimitPrice = $_POST["contingentPrice"];
  $contingentQuantity = $_POST["contingentQuantity"];
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date -> setDate($_POST["year"], $_POST["month"], $_POST["day"]);
  $date -> setTime($_POST["hours"], $_POST["minutes"], $_POST["seconds"]);
  // var_dump($date);
      $query = "INSERT INTO [competitionTrade]
                   ([fullName]
                   ,[date]
                   ,[limitOrder]
                   ,[quantity]
                   ,[tickerSymbol]
                   ,[limitPrice]
                   ,[contingentOrder]
                   ,[contingentQuantity]
                   ,[contingentLimitPrice])
             VALUES
                   (<$fullName, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$date, datetime,>
                   ,<$limitOrder, varchar(50),> //line 29
                   ,<$quantity, int,>
                   ,<$ticSymbol, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$limitPrice, float,>
                   ,<$contingentOrder, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$contingentQuantity, int,>
                   ,<$contingentLimitPrice, float,>)";
      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
```

Edit 1: As per D4V1D's suggestion, I changed it to this:

```
  $fullName = $_POST["fullName"];
      $ticSymbol = $_POST["tickSymbol"];
      $limitOrder = $_POST["limitOrder"];
      $limitPrice = $_POST["limitPrice"];
      $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
      $contingentOrder = $_POST["contingentOrder"];
      $contingentLimitPrice = $_POST["contingentPrice"];
      $contingentQuantity = $_POST["contingentQuantity"];
      $date = new DateTime();
      $date -> setDate($_POST["year"], $_POST["month"], $_POST["day"]);
      $date -> setTime($_POST["hours"], $_POST["minutes"], $_POST["seconds"]);
      // $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      // var_dump($date);
          $query = "INSERT INTO [competitionTrade]
                       ([fullName]
                       ,[date]
                       ,[limitOrder]
                       ,[quantity]
                       ,[tickerSymbol]
                       ,[limitPrice]
                       ,[contingentOrder]
                       ,[contingentQuantity]
                       ,[contingentLimitPrice])
                 VALUES
                       (<$fullName, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), datetime,> //line 29
                       ,<$limitOrder, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$quantity, int,>
                       ,<$ticSymbol, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$limitPrice, float,>
                       ,<$contingentOrder, varchar(50),>
                       ,<$contingentQuantity, int,>
                       ,<$contingentLimitPrice, float,>)";
          $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
```

It now says

> Undefined property: DateTime::$format in **C:\xampp\htdocs\fusion\insertTrade.php** on line **29**

Comment: Insert `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` (which returns a string) instead of inserting just `$date` (which is a `Datetime` object).

Comment: get the actual string sent by PHP to SQL server and try to run it manually. there is a datetime column that is likely formatted the wrong way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to include, for the `[date]` field, the **object** Datetime in the string `$query` (hence the `Object could not be converted to string` error).

You need to do as such:

```
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // $date is now a string
$query = "INSERT INTO [competitionTrade]
                   ([fullName]
                   ,[date]
                   ,[limitOrder]
                   ,[quantity]
                   ,[tickerSymbol]
                   ,[limitPrice]
                   ,[contingentOrder]
                   ,[contingentQuantity]
                   ,[contingentLimitPrice])
             VALUES
                   (<$fullName, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$date, datetime,>
                   ,<$limitOrder, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$quantity, int,>
                   ,<$ticSymbol, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$limitPrice, float,>
                   ,<$contingentOrder, varchar(50),>
                   ,<$contingentQuantity, int,>
                   ,<$contingentLimitPrice, float,>)";
```

Comment: I did as you said, and it returned with `Undefined property: DateTime::$format in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\fusion\insertTrade.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />`

Comment: It's not a property, it's a [method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). Are you sure you are using it the right way?

Comment: Ok. Try then adding `$date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` right before the query and use `$date` in your `$query`. What's the output?