# Insert current day in SQL Server with PHP

Tags: php, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have to insert the current date in my table after finished traitement 
for this I use this code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
//Don't forget this..I had used this..just didn't mention it in the post

$datetime_variable = new DateTime();
$test = date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sqld = "insert into Traitement (dateTraitement) values (date_format($datetime_variable, 'Y-m-d'))";
$stmtd = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sqld);
             if( $stmtd === false ) {
             die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
             }
```

but it gives me this Error:

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in

However, my dateTraitement in my table is datetime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: Try : `$datetime_variable = $datetime_variable->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` or in MySql as suggested in the anwser bellow with `NOW()` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`dateposted`) VALUES (GETDATE())");
```

**you can use GETDATE() function and add today date that's it**

Comment: The question explicitly asks for MS SQL Server, not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

if you want insert current date.then you can use `NOW()`
your query should be

```
 insert into Traitement ('dateTraitement') values (now())
```

Or you can use this also

```
insert into Traitement ('dateTraitement') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

if you are using sql server then you can use `GETDATE()`

```
insert into Traitement ('dateTraitement') values (GETDATE())
```

Comment: i m using sqlserver

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by only using this request

insert into DateTraitement (dateTraitement) values (SYSDATETIME())

thinks for your helps