# Need to pull my data type "DATE" into a display table for PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

The line that is needed to display is the '.$date['entry_date'].'

It will not pull from the SQL Server Table at at data type of Date into the display table.
What am I doing wrong.

```
 <tbody>
    <?php
    $transaction_id = 1;

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);

        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$transaction_id.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['fund'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['department'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['code_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['budget_year'].'</td>
                <td>'.$date['entry_date'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['project_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['item_desc'].'</td>
                <td>'.$amount.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['detail'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['PO'].'</td>

            </tr>';

        $transaction_id++;
    }?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: what is this $date,

Comment: Where is `$query` defined? is the date field included in your query?

Comment: The date has a data type is Date.  i have it listed at

'.$row['entry_date'].'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can't get values from date field.
You can retrieve date and time types (datetime, date, time, datetime2, and datetimeoffset) as strings in these ways:

Set connection option `ReturnDatesAsStrings` to `true`.

```
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>true,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"user",
    "PWD"=>"password"
);
...
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['entry_date'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
...
```

Set connection option `ReturnDatesAsStrings` to `false` and format returned date field value.

```
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings"=>false,
    "Database"=>'database',
    "UID"=>"user",
    "PWD"=>"password"
);
...
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.date_format($row['entry_date'], 'Y-m-d').'</td>
        </tr>';
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

$date should be $row. In your code $date is undefined. However, $row is equal to your SQL query results. $row is an associative array and each value is associated with the SQL field name. Therefore, if you want to display the value from the field 'entry_date' then write $row['entry_date'].

Comment: I thought that would work but it comes with error

Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string 

<td>'.$row['entry_date'].'</td>

Comment: You'll want to refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string

$dateFromDB would be $row['entry_date'].