# Why one MySQL database accepts DateTime and other not?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, symfony, doctrine

**Dev and remote system**

I have a local dev system and deployment system remotely with configuration:

- Php Core: Symfony 4.2
- Mysql: 5.7.26 Innodb
- Linux: 18.x
- Doctrine: 2.x

**Problem description**

The problem is now that I have **DataFixtures** (Symfony demo data generators) which I run to fill out my databse. When I run command to fill the database then for some unknow reason **DateTime** variables are being saved into database without any single problem on **Dev** environment, but when I run the same command on remote server (**prod**) I keep getting:

`PDO Error, Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`.

I cannot figure out where are the database differences, why one database accepts DateTime, and the other won't.

**Already tested/compared**

I've already tried to search for solution for couple of hours:

- was comparing the database configuration variables
- searched for some configurations which maybe turn some convertion of DateTime to string automatically on server side.

Made sure that the source code/config/pages are the same:

- The database structure is 100% the same,
- composer packages are the same,
- entire instance is the same i just copied everything 1:1 with hidden config files as well.
- I also tried to set 
  `@ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=255, nullable=true)`.

**Summary**

The biggest issue is that answers like:

*"You need to insert string value $date->format('y-m-d');"*

is not helping because if I do that then on my dev system I get errors that DateTime or null is expected and I tried to insert string.

Either there is some strange mysql configuration missing or some apache package - I just can't find it.

Let me know if I can provide You some data.

**Example of column definition in entity**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $deadline;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where the column definition at entity level? What about the column types on both databases? Is the same? Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: MySQL versions the same on both? Are the sql modes the same `SELECT @@sql_mode` ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Both versions are the same `5.7.2.6`. Dev and remote are the same: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

Comment: @ReynierPM Like I wrote, I already tried converting. This won't work. Added definition to the description. And yes columns types are the same, checked that as well.

Comment: by any change do you've an stacktrace? the message you show us is not enough to help you. Also more info in how you're creating the entity will help too.

Comment: I... made it run...  not 100% sure why it worked - will add more info/or self response with fix later.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for this seems to be kind of related to symfony. First of all I learned that `Doctrine` has some built in converters which do convert `\DateTime` into `string` (aka DB date) on fly.

So now if we follow that up it means that the working transformation **must** also work on remote **prod** environment.

I actually did 3 things

- switching from `prod` to `dev` in `.env`
- `bin/console cache clear; bin/console cache:warmup`
- `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

Now where is the difference? I kept running my command in `prod` env, with `--env=dev` but the thing is that If You try to run `dev` based command in `prod` then You get an error that command was not found which is very correct as it prevents from running unsafe commands like `purge database`.

So running command in `dev` setted up in `.env` is **the same** (or should, looks like it's not) like runnig command with params `--env=dev`.

This is really all that I just did, hours of checking types, entities, settings just to find this, strange bug.

Also when I switched back to `prod` in `.env` and now i run the command with `--env=dev` everything just works fine so maybe somehow the cache blocked something, maybe some doctrine based sql transformations were cached.