# Trying to assign a DateTimeImmutable to a correctly typed variable gives me a type error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am writing unit tests for web API using phpunit. One of the classes I have to write tests for is called Period, and stores a mandatory start date and an optional end date. On top of being mandatory, the start date also needs to be lower or equal to the end date. To that respect, the following code is written:

```
use DateTimeImmutable;

final class Period
{
    private DateTimeImmutable $startDate;

    private ?DateTimeImmutable $endDate;

    public function __construct(
        DateTimeImmutable $startDate,
        ?DateTimeImmutable $endDate,
    ) {
        $this->validateDates($startDate, $endDate);
        $this->$startDate = $startDate;
        $this->$endDate = $endDate;
    }

    /* Other stuff here*/

    private function validateDates(
        DateTimeImmutable $start,
        ?DateTimeImmutable $end
    ): void {
        if (!is_null($end) && $start > $end) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                'Start Date cannot be later than End Date',
                422
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In the unit test, the first test is a basic object instantiation one:

```
use DateTimeImmutable;

final class PeriodTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function shouldInstantiateNewObject(): void
    {
        $startDate = new DateTimeImmutable('2023-12-20');
        $endDate = new DateTimeImmutable('2023-12-21');

        $period = new Period($startDate, $endDate);

        self::assertSame($startDate, $period->getStartDate());
        self::assertSame($endDate, $period->getEndDate());
    }
}
```

However, when running this test(Or any test with the class Period), I get the following message:

```
There was 1 error:

1) tests\Unit\Domain\ValueObjects\PeriodTest::shouldInstantiateNewObject
Error: Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string

/home/jb3/autodoc/doc-api/src/Domain/ValueObjects/Period.php:28
/home/jb3/autodoc/doc-api/tests/Unit/Domain/ValueObjects/PeriodTest.php:22
```

I have tried to find answers here, [but the one I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209941/object-of-class-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string) has to do with trying to *instantiate* a DateTimeImmutable using a DateTimeImmutable as a parameter, which I don't believe is the case here, since line 28 of the Period class is the first variable assignment, `$this->startDate = $startDate;`, and no new objects are even being explicitly instantiated in the constructor at all.

I am a bit lost as to what I should look into to solve this.

Comment: You have an extra `$` in `$this->$startDate` and `$this->$endDate`.

Comment: Well leave it to the dumdum(me) to miss the obvious! Thx mate, this was it. Would you mind answering so I can accept your answer?